# Excluding files with SevenZipSharp in Code

Tags: c#, .net, compression, sevenzipsharp

I'm currently on a little project where I have to define several paths that need to be compressed into one single zip-file.

Now the following case: One of those paths is a directory, which should be compressed recursively (including all files and sub-folders it contains). Before I compress, I check several things including permissions.
If the current user, which wants to compress, doesn't have the permission to a file or folder it should be excluded.

Now how can I exclude several files and directories from compressing in recursive mode?

I already tried something like this, but the arguement seems to exist only in cmd.

```
compressor.CustomParameters.Add("-x", "@C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\exclude.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any possibility with SevenZipSharp to exclude files.
Instead I use now DotNetZip which has a nice method to remove files:
`ZipFile.RemoveEntry()` and `ZipFile.RemoveEntries()`
e.g.:

```
foreach (string removePath in Verifier.ExcludePaths)
{
    try
    {
        // Remove files and directories to be excluded
        zipFile.RemoveEntry(removePath);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Logger.Warn("Could not exclude path \"{0}\".",removePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that SevenZipSharp can exclude files:

```
SevenZipCompressor sevenZipCompressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
sevenZipCompressor.ModifyArchive(archiveName, dictionary);
// string archiveName: archive name
// Dictionary<int Index, string NewFileName>: NewFileName or Null value to delete the corresponding index.
```