# Why SevenZipSharp creates an empty folder inside the zip?

Tags: c#, 7zip

I want to zip a folder with `.pdf` files using SevenZipSharp.
When I run the following code:

```
private void ZipFiles(string inputFolder)
{
    try
    {
        SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll");
        SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
        compressor.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip;
        compressor.CompressionMode = SevenZip.CompressionMode.Create;
        compressor.TempFolderPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

        string output = inputFolder + @"\TestCycle16.7z";
        compressor.CompressDirectory(inputFolder, output);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error creating zip folder: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

it creates a `.zip` with all `.pdf`s I want but with an extra empty folder named same as the `.zip`. Is this behavior intended?

I have tried commenting out the TempFolderPath, changing folders, different Compression Levels, `PreserveDirectoryRoot = false` and nothing seems to be helping.

Comment: can you not exclude the filename you're creating?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i tried using ModifyArchive i found here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47665073/12148816
But the problem is index of that extra zip inside is usually 0 but if it is not how can i iterate through the .7z folder and find the index of the folder that needs to be deleted?